# Multiple AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask

I have a specific annoying process on my App. The App needs to retrieve from server a list of complex object "Product". Each product object contains an id which refers to the manufacturer Id. So the process is that I request the list of products and for each product I need to request on the manufacturer Id to get the informations related to it. 
The thing is that I use Volley to make requests. As an Asynchronous method, I I cannot make a loop (which is synchronous) to request for each manufacturer. 
I've read about AsyncTask to perform such process. This means that I need to execute an AsyncTask for each product to retrieve its manufacturer information.

I wanted to know if there is another way to manage that because it seems really bad for the performance... If I have 50 product, I will need to make 50 AsyncTasks...

Comment: why don't you ask your server to send the manufacturer's details with in the productlist in your first hit .?

Comment: You need to have a request manager class running a thread pool maybe of 5 threads. This class can take requests and a callback and also make sure that you don't overuse the resources.

Comment: Don't have the permission to modify the server side processes.....

Comment: i think you need to create a web service that will take a array of product id's and return a list of detail in one web request :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to do something from the tasks in the foreground when they end, you could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to run the requests using a fixed amount of threads (as you probably don't want to start 50 threads).

If you need to know when they have all finished, you can use some synchronization tools from the java.util.concurrent package, like a [CyclicBarrier](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or an [AtomicInteger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling multiple times, better way is download the product details from your server and save it in sqlite db. when ever it is required you can use it.